# How to call a node from a xml file within asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net, html, xml, vb.net

I am trying to use the value of `<Directory>` in my following piece of code:

```
 Public Function GetFile() As String
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(< Directory >)
    Dim files As FileSystemInfo() = di.GetFileSystemInfos()
    Dim newestFile = files.OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.CreationTime).First
    Return newestFile.FullName
End Function
```

Is there any way i can call the value stored in the xml file in my code?

Comment: Which XML file are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andy's answer is good, but in VB it's even easier.

```
Dim xmlDoc As XDocument
Dim dir as String
xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml")
dir = xmlDoc.<ServerList>.<Server>.<Directory>.First().Value;
```

Or even easier if the XML file will never have more than one `<Directory>` element that you care about:

```
dir = xmlDoc...<Directory>.First().Value;
```

To answer your comment on Andy's answer:

```
dir = (From server as XElement in xmlDoc...<Server>
      Where server.<ServerName>.First().Value = requiredServer
      Select server.<Directory>.First().Value)(0);
```

Comment: Could i use this code in a similar way if i wanted to populate an asp drop-down-list with the server names in the xml file?

Comment: Absolutely - `From server as XElement in xmlDoc...<Server> Select server.<ServerName>.First().Value` will give you an `IEnumerable(Of String)` containing the server names.

Answer (score 3):

As you are clearly familiar with Linq, you can operate on the Xml using System.Xml.Linq.

Apologies, this is in c#.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
var dir = xDoc.Element("ServerList").Elements("Server").Elements("Directory").First().Value;
```

If you have the Xml stored in a string replace XDocument.Load with XDocument.Parse.

Obviously you'll have to defend against parse errors, file missing and schema inconsistencies in your production code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works perfectly. However, if i allowed the user to select what server they wanted, and wrote their choice to a variable, how would i select the correct xml node then?

Comment: Add a where clause, similar to this  var dir = xDoc.Element("ServerList").Elements("Server").Where(svr => svr.Element("ServerName").Value == "T2").Elements("Directory").First().Value;

Answer (score 1):

You can use this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301225

Comment: Linq to XML is MUCH easier than this.